# Did Archimedes know Archimedes' recurrence formula?

Tags: mathematics, archimedes, greek-mathematics

Archimedes used polygons inscribed and circumscribed to the circle to approximate pi in his "[Measurement of a Circle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurement_of_a_Circle)".

However, I think [Archimedes' recurrence formula](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArchimedesRecurrenceFormula.html) is not used there.

Did Archimedes know Archimedes' recurrence formula?

Comment: Ancient math has no algebraic formulas.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA If he had followed the same procedure as for the formula, then we can assume that he knew it.

Comment: No. You can read his procedure [here](https://nonagon.org/ExLibris/sites/default/files/pdf/Archimedes-Circle.pdf), and modern commentary [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.5951/mathteacher.110.1.0071). It is "the same" only in the sense that he did iteratively double the number of sides and related the ratios before and after the doubling. But he did it geometrically, and even after symbolic conversion it takes a fair amount of algebraic and trigonometric manipulations to tidy it up into Wolfram's geometric and harmonic means. He'd be surprised and amused by the result.